# Escape characters in bash & expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I have problem when trying to run interactive script, with following :

expect "Enter the Primary Management Server hostname or IP address [127.0.0.1] : "  { send -- "127.0.0.1\r" }

It dose not submit the response to the interactive script and I thinks the issue is here [127.0.0.1], is there a way to escape []?

Comment: Please search before asking. The `-gl` flag disables globbing, or add a dash before the pattern string, or double-backslash the opening square bracket.

Comment: Solved it by \\\[127.0.0.1\\\]